# mglearn.discrete_scatter(X_train[:, 0], X_train[:, 1], y_train)の意味について

Tags: python

下記の `mglearn.discrete_scatter(X_train[:, 0], X_train[:, 1], y_train)` の
 `X_train[:, 0], X_train[:, 1]` というところはどういう意味ですか？
このコードを打つと点がグラフに表記されました。

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons

X, y = make_moons(n_samples=100, noise=0.25, random_state=3)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y,
                                                random_state=42)

mlp = MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs', random_state=0).fit(X_train, y_train)
mglearn.plots.plot_2d_separator(mlp, X_train, fill=True, alpha=.3)
mglearn.discrete_scatter(X_train[:, 0], X_train[:, 1], y_train)
plt.xlabel("Feature 0")
plt.ylabel("Feature 1")
```

参照：pythonではじめる機械学習

Answer (score 2):

NumPy の array に対するスライスです。

array には `[a:b]` のように書くと `a` 以上 `b` 未満のインデックスの要素を切り取れる機能があるのですが、更に `[:]` と書くと全ての要素への指定になります。

今回の場合それを多次元 array に使っています。たとえば `[:, 0]` だと「第1次元は全ての要素、第2次元は0番目だけ」、つまり、全ての要素の先頭だけとってくる、という指定になります。

```py
# Python 3.6.0, NumPy 1.13.1
>>> import numpy as np
>>> sample = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
>>> sample[0:2]
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
>>> sample[:, 0]
array([1, 4, 7])
>>> sample[:, 1]
array([2, 5, 8])
>>>
```

#### 参考

- [Indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) -- NumPy v1.13 Manual
- [NumPy配列のスライス表記の参照と代入](https://hydrocul.github.io/wiki/numpy/ndarray-ref-slice.html) -- hydroculのメモ